# Java2D Painting "noisy" gray backgrounds (Metallic look)

Tags: paint, java-2d, effect

I was wandering how to reproduce the following effect in java 2d:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a `java.awt.TexturePaint` to fill your shapes is probably the easiest and most straightforward way to do it. You could load a texture image from a file or create it in a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` on the fly.